# Sms logs - Content resolver

Tags: android, logging, sms

I have  few question about sms logs. Some of them are on the forum but I just want to get another opinion.

First of all I have read that it is not recommanded to use Content resolver for sms(getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"..)) ) because it's not in the official api. Do you think there is a better way to get this information?

I would like also to trigger an action(like starting a service) when a message is received/sent. For received messages you can add a broadcast receiver with android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED. Is there a way to do this also for the sent messages? From what I have seen Content observer works only when application is active and I would want something that can function all the time.

I want to know if there is a way to query deleted sms(including with Content resolver).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think there is a better way to get this information?

Better? No. There is worse - to obtain root privileges and query SMS db directly.

> I want to know if there is a way to query deleted sms(including with
>   Content resolver).

I guess when data is deleted from db there's no way to get it back.

Comment: I know that there are some restore apps that can restore deleted messages(I could be wrong). In this case maybe the messages are not deleted but just moved to a different table. I don't know how it's done but I didn't find any documentation about this.